# Shrink ReFS partition

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2016, refs

How can I shrink a ReFS partition (under any OS, most convenient would be Windows Server 2016)?

diskmgmt.msc doesn't supports shrinking of ReFS, neither does gparted. From what I've read in the whitepaper it should be possible to shrink ReFS.

Just how? Extending worked fine and without any warning....

Comment: I would very much like to know this as well. I was in a situation where I replaced my 1TB SSD however I couldn't rebuild my mirror because the newer disk was 20GBs smaller than the old one. I found then the hard way that there was no implemented way to shrink the partition. Apparently there's no way added to the system to actually do this operation although it's supported by the filesystem itself. Seems Microsoft didn't think this would be an important feature

Comment: You might want to upvote the feature request in uservoice for this to maybe get some attention at https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295056-storage/suggestions/16615756-support-to-shrink-refs-partition

Comment: @gabtzi uservoice is, as far I see, not connected in any way with microsoft. Reaching out to MS directly may is the better way as they are the ones who push ReFS the most. From the amount of upvotes of my question (one down and one up) it looks like resizing a partition is utterly exotic which surprises me.

Comment: If you have some business support from Microsoft since you're using a Server License it would be great if you could contact them directly and let them know how important it is. Digging up through the various "Microsoft" fora didn't make any difference to the users that posted anything so I'm guessing only direct customer support would help. Other than tha, I don't see any other way to let them know how important a feature this is other than fill the internet :D